# While saving a MSWord document programatically "Save As" dialog shows file type as .htm instead of .doc

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-word

I am creating a MS-Word document from my C# (ASP.Net) code. It works fine except for one thing. When the user clicks on the "Open" button on the browser prompt the file opens up in MS Word and the title can be seen as "testList_Amit1.doc".

[image]

[image]

But, when the user clicks on the "Save As" button from the File menu in the Ms Word application ribbon, the "Save As" dialog shows "Web Page (*.htm;*.html)" in the "Save as Type:" dropdown, instead of ".doc".

[image]

Below is the code snippet i am using for this.

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

    //File name for the exported word document
    string strFileName = filename + ".doc";

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + strFileName);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vndopenxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-16";

    StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();

    String wordHeader = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' ";
    wordHeader += "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' ";
    wordHeader += "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'> ";

    wordHeader += "<head><title>" + filename + "</title>";
    wordHeader += "<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><w:WordDocument><w:View>Normal</w:View><w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>";
    wordHeader += "<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/></w:WordDocument></xml><![endif]-->";
    wordHeader += "<style> @page Section1 {size:8.5in 11.0in; mso-first-footer:ff1; mso-footer: f1; mso-header: h1; ";
    wordHeader += "margin:1.00in 0.75in 1.00in 0.75in; ";
    wordHeader += "mso-paper-source:0;} ";
    wordHeader += "div.Section1 {page:Section1;} p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, ";
    wordHeader += "div.MsoFooter{margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt; ";
    wordHeader += "mso-pagination:widow-orphan; tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in; ";
    wordHeader += "font-size:8.0pt; } ";
    wordHeader += "table.tableHeader {margin:0in; font-size:12.0pt; } ";
    wordHeader += "table.tableData {margin:0in; font-size:10.0pt; width:100%; } --></style></head>";

    strHTMLContent.Append(wordHeader);
    strHTMLContent.Append("<body><div class=Section1>");
    .
    .
    .
    .
    strHTMLContent.Append("</div></body></html>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Comment: That all looks like HTML to me, not a [.doc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word#Binary_formats_.28Word_97.E2.80.932007.29).

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a library to create a word file?

Comment: @KSib that's one of our legacy codes. This is how it was written and I see a lot of people in past have used this way to export content to MS-Word (.doc). As i said this is working fine also except for the file type displayed in the Save As dialog.